# Pivot data frame with selected value

Tags: r, pivot-table, reshape

I have this data frame

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Type = c("Date", "Text", "Value", "Text", "Date", "Value", "Value", "Text", "Date" ), Parameter = c("2020-2-3", "String", 9.99, "String", "2020-2-4", 0, 10, "String", "2020-2-5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,                                                                                                                           -9L))
```

I would like to get this

```
    ID  Type    Parameter      Date
    1   Text    String         2020-2-3
    1   Value   9.99           2020-2-3
    2   Text    String         2020-2-4 
    2   Value   0              2020-2-4 
    3   Value   10             2020-2-5
    3   Text    String         2020-2-5
```

My idea was

`pivot_wider(names_from = Type, values_from = Parameter)`

But it pivot all columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `Type = Date` values in a new column and `fill` them with previous values for each `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = replace(Parameter, Type != 'Date', NA)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  fill(Date, .direction = 'updown') %>%
  ungroup %>%
  filter(Type != 'Date') 
 
#     ID Type  Parameter Date    
#  <int> <chr> <chr>     <chr>   
#1     1 Text  String    2020-2-3
#2     1 Value 9.99      2020-2-3
#3     2 Text  String    2020-2-4
#4     2 Value 0         2020-2-4
#5     3 Value 10        2020-2-5
#6     3 Text  String    2020-2-5
```

Comment: Thank you. It works only if Date is first in group (as in my sample data frame). Could you provide more robust code. I think group_by would do the thing.

Comment: @onhalu Can you provide an example which is closer to your actual data?

Comment: I just edited my post. If I use your code ID 2 has date from ID 1 (2020-2-3) in first row. And ID 3 has date from ID 2 (2020-2-4) instead of 2020-2-5. Thank you for your time.

Comment: grouping by `ID` before using `fill` should solve it. Try the updated answer @onhalu